# How to effect new changes to user dashboards in alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

If I were to change user/site dashboard preset(s), is it possible to effect the change(s) to already created users in alfresco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This I have only tried out in 4.2.c.
I navigated to the surf-config/components directory in the explorer (Very well hidden so use the left explorer pane) and manually deleted the xml configs for users. (Or run a javascript script from javascript console which does the same thing), afterwards I used the surf console tool to refresh all components and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

See this Share webscript : /components/dashboard/customise-dashboard
I use this script a long time ago, so I don't remind very well the parameters needed... but there is a property in the object parameter you must avoid...

EDIT : execute script /components/dashboard/customise-dashboard with POST method

Here an example of the request body :

```
{
    "dashboardPage": "site/site1/dashboard",
    "templateId": "dashboard-2-columns-wide-right",
    "dashlets": [
        {
            "url": "/components/dashlets/site-links",
            "regionId": "component-1-1",
            "originalRegionId": "component-1-1"
        },
        {
            "url": "/components/dashlets/calendar",
            "regionId": "component-1-2",
            "originalRegionId": "component-1-2"
        },
        {
            "url": "/components/dashlets/wiki",
            "regionId": "component-1-3",
            "originalRegionId": "component-2-3"
        },
        {
            "url": "/components/dashlets/docsummary",
            "regionId": "component-2-1",
            "originalRegionId": "component-2-1"
        },
        {
            "url": "/components/dashlets/activityfeed",
            "regionId": "component-2-2",
            "originalRegionId": "component-2-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll look at this script next week but on first glance it seems I would have to call this script to update per user.

Comment: Yes you would need to set this for all users, but you could use my [share-import-export](http://code.google.com/p/share-import-export/) scripts (Python) as a basis for grabbing a list of all users and setting the dashboard contents of each using a script.

Comment: Just an update. I navigated to the surf-config/components directory in the explorer and for a test manually deleted the xml configs for a user. I restarted the repository and logged in as that user. The user homepage is just blank now.